# Unable to use fopen More Than Once in YASM Assembly

Tags: linux, assembly, x86-64, calling-convention

Essentially what I am attempting to do is make a copy of a file--really, it's a lot more, but I can't get past this first hurdle--using YASM assembly on x86_64 Linux. My problem is that I seem to be unable to use fopen more than once.

My code so far:

```
segment .data
RW  dd  "w+", 0             ; RW -- read write (creates)
RO  dd  "r" , 0             ; RO -- read only
po  dq  0                   ; po -- pointer original
pn  dq  0                   ; pn -- pointer new

    segment .text

    global border
    extern fopen
    extern fclose
    extern fputc

border:
    push rbp
    mov rbp, rsp

    mov r8, rdi             ; r8 -- the original file name
    mov r9, rsi             ; r9 -- the destination file

    mov rdi, r8
    lea rsi, [RO]
    call fopen
    mov [po], rax

    mov rdi, r9
    lea rsi, [RW]
    call fopen
    mov [pn], rax

    mov rdi, "B"   ; Just a test to know if worked.
    mov rsi, [pn]
    call fputc

EXIT:
    mov rdi, [po]
    call fclose
    mov rdi, [pn]
    call fclose
    mov rsp, rbp
    pop rbp
    ret
```

And it's called from the following C program:

```
char* source = "TestNorm.txt";
char* dest = "TestDest.txt";
border(source, dest);
```

I've tried a few things, but ultimately it comes down to the second fopen not working--the file is not opened, and I obviously get a seg fault when I try to use the file pointer for it--but the first one works perfectly.

I'm utterly stumped on this one. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: `r9` is a caller saved register, meaning it can be destroyed by functions you call. PS: read the ABI documentation, and learn to use a debugger.

Comment: Besides a debugger, use `strace` to trace the args your code is passing to system calls.

Comment: I've tried incrementing the two registers by two (so I'm now working r10, and r11, but I still get seg faults in the same place.